# A customer queue where service time is exponentially distributed and arrival governed by a Poisson process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, generating-functions, laplace-transform, poisson-process

I have just started Poisson processes in my course on stochastic processes. We have just covered random sums and now I got the following tutorial/ exercise class question, but I don't quite see what is expected:

> Customers arrive at a cashier according to a Poisson process with intensity $
> \lambda$. The service
> time of each customer is exponentially distributed with mean $\frac{1}{\mu}$. At time $0$, there is one
> customer being served. Let $Z$ be the number of customers that arrive during this customer's
> service time. Show that $Z$ has the following generating function:
> $$ G_Z(r)= \frac{\mu}{\mu + \lambda (1-r)}$$

---

This function looks a lot like the exponential generating function $\frac{\mu}{\mu + s}$, which makes sense since the service time is exponentially distributed with parameter $\mu $. However, instead of the variable $s$, we see a $\lambda(1+r)$. Can someone help me  a bit through the reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the additional service time for the existing customer time is $S \sim \text{Exp}(\mu)$.

Then the number of arrivals in time $S$ is $Z\sim \text{Pois}(\lambda S)$

This implies $$\mathbb P(Z=a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda s} \frac{\lambda^a s^a}{a!} \mu e^{-\mu s}\, ds = \frac{\lambda^a \mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^{a+1}}= \frac{\frac{\mu}{\lambda}}{\left(1+\frac{\mu}{\lambda}\right)^{a+1}}$$ which is the probability mass function of a geometric random variable on $0,1,2,3,\ldots$ where the probability of "success" (here the service time finishing before another customer joins the queue) is $\frac{\mu}{\lambda}$.  You could have jumped straight to this result using a memoryless argument.

The probability generating function is then $$G_Z(r) = \mathbb E(r^Z) =\sum_{a=0}^\infty r^a \frac{\frac{\mu}{\lambda}}{\left(1+\frac{\mu}{\lambda}\right)^{a+1}}  = \frac{\frac{\mu}{\lambda}}{\left(1+\frac{\mu}{\lambda}-r\right)}=\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda(1-r)}$$

which is almost what you stated in the question, but with a sign change.

Comment: What do you do in your first step here:
$\mathbb P(Z=a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda s} \frac{\lambda^a s^a}{a!} \mu e^{-\mu s}\, ds $, the calculus makes sense, but I don't quite understand WHY we are interested in this integral in particular. I have trouble "reading" what is happening.

Comment: I see the product of two probability functions, namely a Poisson probability and an exponential probability. What is the reasoning behind taking the product?

Comment: @Algebrageek this is the law of total probability.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.